# Python parse nested lists with unknown depth

Tags: python, python-2.7

my code looks like this it parses the list for keywords spits out theyr position and then gives it to arc which replaces the position with a calculated code thereby deleting some levels of depth. 
It actually works but i am now up to add 2 or 3 more levels of depth and i looking for something that is more elegant and more robust and can handle infinitive levels of depth .

edit: I want to make operations in a list, the list should be able to handle simple code like plus, minus, i also want to add an if condition. in an list it would look like this:

sb.append (...['mul', -0.20,'hpt' ]...)

The list is for a game every list is a spell which can alter the stats of a target. I try to write the languge to design the spells as verbose as possible so i want to add an if condition and maybe later other basic operations as well:

"sb.append (...if 'hp' > 'mp':['mul', -0.20,'hpt' ]...)"  (the strings are converted to numbers before)

however the list is written outside of the function and written before the variables are declared and maybe even imported so i prefer escaped code.

```
def parseop(tmpsp):
    for y in range ( len (tmpsp) ):
        if type(tmpsp[y]) is list:
            for x in range ( len (tmpsp[y]) ):
                if type(tmpsp[y][x]) is list:
                    for z in range ( len (tmpsp[y][x]) ):                               
                        if type(tmpsp[y][x][z]) is list:
                            for t in range ( len (tmpsp[y][x][z]) ): 
                                if type(tmpsp[y][x][z][t]) is list:
                                    for e in range ( len (tmpsp[y][x][z][t]) ): 
                                        if arn(tmpsp[y][x][z][t][e]): tmpcn.append([y,x,z,t])
                                if arn(tmpsp[y][x][z][t]): tmpcn.append([y,x,z])
                        if arn(tmpsp[y][x][z]): tmpcn.append([y,x])
                if arn(tmpsp[y][x]): tmpcn.append([y])
    if len (tmpcn):
        tmpcn.reverse()
        for x in range ( len (tmpcn) ):
            dprint ((tmpcn, len (tmpcn[x])))
            if len (tmpcn[x]) ==4:   tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]][tmpcn[x][1]][tmpcn[x][2]][tmpcn[x][3]] = arg(tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]][tmpcn[x][1]][tmpcn[x][2]][tmpcn[x][3]])
            elif len (tmpcn[x]) ==3:   tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]][tmpcn[x][1]][tmpcn[x][2]] = arg(tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]][tmpcn[x][1]][tmpcn[x][2]])
            elif len (tmpcn[x]) ==2: tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]][tmpcn[x][1]]              = arg(tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]][tmpcn[x][1]])
            elif len (tmpcn[x]) ==1: tmpsp[tmpcn[x][0]] 

def arg(tmp):
    ddprint ('arg',tmp)
    if tmp[0] == 'mul': 
        del tmp[0]
        for d in range ( len (tmp) ): 
            if ifa(tmp[d]):
                tmp[d] = ifa(tmp[d])

        ddprint ((arg, tmp))
        tmp = m(*tmp)
        ddprint ((arg, tmp))
        return tmp
    elif tmp[0] == 'div': 
        del tmp[0]
        for d in range ( len (tmp) ): 
            if ifa(tmp[d]):
                tmp[d] = ifa(tmp[d])
        tmp = d(*tmp)
        ddprint ((arg, tmp))
        return tmp
    elif tmp[0] == 'add': 
        del tmp[0]
        for d in range ( len (tmp) ): 
            if ifa(tmp[d]):
                tmp[d] = ifa(tmp[d])
        ddprint('add',tmp)
        tmp = a(*tmp)
        ddprint ((arg, tmp))
        return tmp
    else: print 'There is trouble in arg'

def arn(tmp):
    ddprint ('arn',tmp)
    if tmp == 'mul': return 1
    if tmp == 'div': return 1
    if tmp == 'add': return 1
```

Comment: looks like a job for recursion

Comment: Could you add more context about what you are trying to do? If you are working with multi-dimensional arrays of data and doing math on that data, have a look a numpy: http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: i want to convert code in a list into number, the list could look like this:sb.append (['magic','black hole', [[['mag'],'hp', ['mul', -0.20,'hpt' ]], [['mag'],'mana',['mul', -0.20, 'manat']]]])
i also would like to add an if condition to the possible converted code but yet i dont know how

Comment: extendet some informations